# Menu loop in 2 different methods Java program

Tags: java, loops, menu, infinite-loop, do-while

I am working on a menu program and I want to be able to enter as many selections as I want without the menu looping as well after the input, currently it either infinite-loops, or the program ends after one input, being unable to perform a different selection after the first. Also I want to have a case where I exit the menu if I press 0.

```
public void showMenu() {

    System.out.println("Welcome!");
    System.out.println("Select an option:\n" +
            "1. Adunare\n" +
            "2. Scadere\n" +
            "3. Inmultire\n" +
            "4. Impartire\n" +
            "5. Comparare numere\n" +
            "6. List To Hundred\n" +
            "7. Nr to list\n" +
            "8. Contains\n" +
            "9. Even numbers\n" +
            "10. List of Strings\n" +
            "11. Second largest number\n" +
            "12. Second lowest number\n" +
            "13. Number \n" +
            "14. Number 2 \n" +
            "15. Number 3\n" +
            "16. String\n" +
            "17. String 2\n" +
            "18. Amount of snow\n" +
            "19. Eligible to vote test\n" +
            "20. Odd or even\n" +
            "21. Dog\n" +
            "22. Cat\n" +
            "23. Elev");

}


public void runProgram() {
    showMenu();
    int numberFromUser = citire.readNumbers();


    do {
        switch (numberFromUser) {
            case 1:
                addition();
                break;
            case 2:
                subtraction();
                break;
            case 3:
                multiply();
                break;
            case 4:
                divide();
                break;
            case 5:
                comparareNumere();
                break;
            case 6:
                listhundred();
                break;
            case 7:
                setnumbertolist();
                break;
            case 8:
                contain();
                break;
            case 9:
                limit();
                break;
            case 10:
                list();
                break;
            case 11:
                secmax();
                break;
            case 12:
                secmin();
                break;
            case 13:
                nr();
                break;
            case 14:
                nr2();
                break;
            case 15:
                nr3();
                break;
            case 16:
                string();
                break;
            case 17:
                string2();
                break;
            case 18:
                weather();
                break;
            case 19:
                eligible();
                break;
            case 20:
                oddoreven();
                break;
            case 21:
                dog();
                break;
            case 22:
                cat();
                break;
            case 23:
                elev();
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
    } while (numberFromUser != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

> numberFromUser = citire.readNumbers();

into the loop to take numbers in the loop.

```
public void runProgram() {
   showMenu();
   int numberFromUser;

   do {
       numberFromUser = citire.readNumbers();
       switch (numberFromUser) {
        case 1:
            addition();
            break;
        case 2:
            subtraction();
            break;
        case 3:
            multiply();
            break;
        case 4:
            divide();
            break;
        case 5:
            comparareNumere();
            break;
        case 6:
            listhundred();
            break;
        case 7:
            setnumbertolist();
            break;
        case 8:
            contain();
            break;
        case 9:
            limit();
            break;
        case 10:
            list();
            break;
        case 11:
            secmax();
            break;
        case 12:
            secmin();
            break;
        case 13:
            nr();
            break;
        case 14:
            nr2();
            break;
        case 15:
            nr3();
            break;
        case 16:
            string();
            break;
        case 17:
            string2();
            break;
        case 18:
            weather();
            break;
        case 19:
            eligible();
            break;
        case 20:
            oddoreven();
            break;
        case 21:
            dog();
            break;
        case 22:
            cat();
            break;
        case 23:
            elev();
            break;
        default:
            break;

       }
   } while (numberFromUser != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `runProgram` to following :

```
public void runProgram()
{
int numberFromUser;
showMenu();
while(true)
{
System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
numberFromUser = citire.readNumbers();
switch(NumberFromUser)
{
   // All your case statements
 case 0: System.exit(0);
}
}
}
```